# Installing cx_Freeze 5.0.2 with Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am running ubuntu 16. I have both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed. I want to install `cx_freeze` latest version for python3. I downloaded the package from their website but couldn't run the `setup.py` file as it always gave me errors. Also i have installed pip3, but it still doesn't work for me. all the answers online are for older version of `cx_freeze` so a fresh answer for the new version will be helpful.

I install and upgrade pip3 with:

```
sudo -H install --upgrade pip
```

then I try to install cx_freeze with:

```
pip3 install cx_Freeze .
```

then i get the following errors:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ngco46uq/cx-Freeze/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q3n3cd2r-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ngco46uq/cx-Freeze/
```

also anyone can tell me any other method to do so ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the error has anything to do with the pip version,  but since you mention it, here are my 2 cents about how you upgraded pip: usually you need to upgrade it via pip itself by running `pip install --upgrade pip`, so you might want to try that. Also, assuming your method does update pip, I'm not sure if you updated pip2 or pip3. What does `which pip` return? I'd try `pip3 install --upgrade pip3`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Pip3 using :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

If you have Python 2.7, you can try alternatives like py2exe